# IOS Simulator Software Keyboard Not Appearing

Tags: flutter, android-studio, input, keyboard, ios-simulator

Software Keyboard in IOS Simulator is not appearing and showing an error in the console using Android Studio and Flutter:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart': Failed assertion: line 790 pos 16: '(data.physical == 0 && data.logical == 0) ||
           (data.physical != 0 && data.logical != 0)': is not true.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To temporarily fix this, toggle:

> I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

You will now be able to use the software keyboard and not the hardware one.

Comment: This should be fixed by Apple after the IOS 15 update. I'll be waiting....

Comment: I am running a simulator with iOS 15.5 and it's happening. I don't know if it matters that I'm running the Flutter app from VS Code, or not.

Comment: @CarlSmith it shouldn't matter. Did the answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, the workaround fixed the problem, which is why I upvoted the answer. In an effort to help others who come along later, I commented that Apple had not fixed it in iOS 15.